# Hide div based on the change of input field in an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am working with Square. I am using the SqPaymentForm. This generates form fields in an iframe. I need to access the id of the input field in the iframe to check for onchange or on so that I can Hide a div tag I am using for errors.

I have tried the following code to hide the div but it does nothing:

```
$('#sq-card-number').on(function(){
    $('#cardNumber').hide();
 }
```

Comment: are you trying onchange function? then change it to
`$('element').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
})`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).on('change', '#sq-card-number', function() {
  $('#cardNumber').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the DOM elements inside iFrame using following code :

`$(document).ready(function(){
    var iFrameDOM = $("iframe#frameID").contents();
    iFrameDOM.find('#cardNumber').hide();
});`

**Note:** *Replace `#frameID` with your iFrame ID*

Answer (score -1):

```
if (document.getElementById("sq-card-number").value === "something") {
   $('#cardNumber').hide();
} else {
   $('#cardNumber').show();
}
```